# Show a usercontrol in MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, expression-blend-4

I my project I have the MainForm with 2 UserControls. 
The UserControl1 have a button that makes the UserControl2 Visible.

Here's what I did:

USERCONTROL1

```
    private void Button1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        mw.CallMethod();
    }
```

MAINWINDOW

```
    public void CallMethod()
    {
        USERCONTROL2 UC2 = new USERCONTROL2();
        UC2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        grid.Children.Add(UC2);

    }
```

...but when I click the UserControl1's button, nothing is happening.

Comment: you create a new mainwindow from your mouse left button up callback, within your usercontrol, that's living inside your mainwindow. Ehm, you got something backwards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare in your background code following:

```
Private Visibility _vis_UC_2;
Public Visibility vis_UC2
{
get
{
   return _vis_UC2;
}
set
{
   _vis_UC2 = value;
   OnPropertyChanged("vis_UC2");
}
}
```

Don't forget to add `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your class

Then you bind your UserControl's visibility to vis_UC2.

In Constructor set starting visibility such as following

```
Public Void MainWindow()
{
   InitializeCompotenents();
   vis_UC2 = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

and finally under your button click you only say the following:

```
vis_UC2 = Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your Form a `panel` and do this:

```
UserControl1 u1 = new UserControl1();
UserControl2 u2 = new UserControl2();

// When you want UserControl1.
u2.Hide();
u1.Show();
u1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel1.Controls.Add(u1);

// When you want UserControl2.
u1.Hide();
u2.Show();
u2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel1.Controls.Add(u2);
```